# Music database c#

Tags: c#, id3

I'm trying to create a link with the ID3v1TagReader so it can convert ID3 tags to string and display them in my program.

The code I'm using to do this is :

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //This is refrencing the Tag Reader
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ID3v1TagReader tr = new ID3v1TagReader();

            ID3v1TagReader.ID3v1Tag ti = new ID3v1TagReader.ID3v1Tag();

            //This is telling the tag reader in which field the information must go
            ti = tr.ReadID3v1Tag(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            trackTextBox.Text = ti.TrackName;
            artistTextBox.Text = ti.ArtistsName;
            albumTextBox.Text = ti.AlbumName;
            comboBox1.Text = ti.Genres;
            locationTextBox.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            yearTextBox.Text = ti.Year;
        }
    }
```

The line "ID3v1TagReader.ID3v1Tag ti = new ID3v1TagReader.ID3v1Tag();" gives the error:  "The type name 'ID3v1Tag' does not exist in the type 'ID3v1TagReader'"

Comment: It sounds like you're missing a reference.

Comment: Where do these guys come from: `ID3v1TagReader` and `ID3v1Tag` ? Are you developing a tag reader? Did you get these classes from somewhere on the internet?

Comment: What library are you using?  You are definitely missing a reference.   Did you add the .DLL for the ID3v1TagReader to your Project References?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the library I think you're using (SharpTag, that I found arbitrarily around the internet), it seems the type `ID3v1Tag` is indeed not inside `ID3v1TagReader`. Try this instead:

```
//This is refrencing the Tag Reader
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        ID3v1TagReader tr = new ID3v1TagReader();

        ID3v1Tag ti = new ID3v1Tag();

        //This is telling the tag reader in which field the information must go
        ti = tr.ReadID3v1Tag(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        trackTextBox.Text = ti.TrackName;
        artistTextBox.Text = ti.ArtistsName;
        albumTextBox.Text = ti.AlbumName;
        comboBox1.Text = ti.Genres;
        locationTextBox.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        yearTextBox.Text = ti.Year;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any `ReadID3v1Tag` method in that class, either.

Comment: @MusiGenesis Now that you mention it... Plus, in that library the class name is `ID3V1TagReader` not `ID3v1TagReader`... whoops!